# Cypher sorting by number of related nodes?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm learning Cypher and I created a "Criminal investigation" project on `Neo4j`.

I'm trying to run a query that outputs each `Person` that has **two** children (`Person`) and both of the children must have committed a crime. To achieve this, I was testing some queries with a `Person` (`p`) called `p.name = "Lillian"` so I know this person has two children but just one of them has committed a crime.

In order to make this I execute this query (return something if Lillian has two sons that committed crimes or return nothing contrarily:

```
match (p:Person)-[r:FAMILY_REL]->(s:Person)
where p.name = "Lillian" 
and size((p)-[:FAMILY_REL]->()-[:PARTY_TO]->(:Crime))=2 and size((p)-[:FAMILY_REL]->()) = 2
return p, s
```

As I already knew Lillian has only one son who committed a crime, the query should have not returned anything but it returned both of their children.

I'm guessing the wrong part of the query is here:

```
where /*...*/ and size((p)-[:FAMILY_REL]->()-[:PARTY_TO]->(:Crime))=2
```

I think this is counting just the number of children instead the number of children who have committed crimes.

What would be the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
MATCH (p:Person)
WHERE p.name = "Lillian" AND size((p)-[:FAMILY_REL]->()) = 2
WITH p, [(p)-[:FAMILY_REL]->(child) WHERE (child)-[:PARTY_TO]->(:Crime) | child] as childCriminals
WHERE size(childCriminals) = 2
UNWIND childCriminals as s
RETURN p, s
```

Note that this will only work if Lillian has exactly two children, and both have been party to a crime.

As for why your query wasn't working, it's likely that one of the children was party to two crimes, that would produce results.

Comment: Thanks, it solved my issue! One last thing, what does this do on the query ` ... | child]`? It's the only part of it I can't understand and I can't find any documentation.

Comment: The pipe here is just a separator between the pattern + WHERE clause, and the projection of what to pull from the pattern to populate the list. So in this case, it's doing the equivalent of: `OPTIONAL MATCH (p)-[:FAMILY_REL]->(child) WHERE (child)-[:PARTY_TO]->(:Crime)` then collecting `child` from each matching path into a list and aliasing it as `childCriminals`